# Escaping slashes and left square brackets when using sed replace

Tags: shell, sed

I have to write short script to replace line in file. Some of the lines contains slashes and left square brackets (probably right also).

I know that another delimiter should be used to replace line with slashes.

My code:

```
sed -i -e "s|${oldLine}|${newLine}|g"
```

This throws an error because line contains [.

Example String in line to change (oldLine variable):

```
// List exampleList = [
```

Example how like should look after change:

```
List exampleList = [
```

How to make it works when there are some chars like [

To reproduce:

```
sed -i -e 's|// List exampleList = [|List exampleList = [|g' test.txt
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Example added

Comment: Please add your **desired output** for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I don't fully understand what you need. There is an example what is passed to that script as oldLine and newLine

Comment: Without putting too fine a point on it .. Can't you simply remove the bracket in the variable ..  OR escape it prior to `sed` IE `\[`  ?   --  It seems to me that `// List exampleList =` should be *plenty* for a search replace ..  Is there a reason you have to include the bracket?

Comment: @Zak I can't remove it. i.e. if there will be line like // List exampleList = [someValue, and if i will remove bracket it will execute something like: sed -i -e 's|// List exampleList = someValue,|List exampleList = someValue|g' test.txt . It will be not replaced

Comment: Can you use `PERL` It would be far simpler .. IE `perl -p -e 's/$ENV{SearchVar}/$ENV{ReplaceVar}/g' test.txt` ?

Comment: If you weren't using variables, you would have to write `sed -i -e 's|// List exampleList = \[|List exampleList = \[|g' test.txt`. As you are using variables, you need to ensure that the variables contain valid snippets of `sed` so that after expansion, the argument is a complete, valid `sed` script. `sed` itself doesn't take parameters and can't do the escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the "bad" characters in $oldline and $newline. The command

```
sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g; s/\([[&()/\]]\)/\\\1/g'
```

will replace `\,[,&,(,),/,]` with `\\,\[`, etc. So the combined command

```
sed -e "s/$(echo $oldline | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g; s/\([[&()/\]]\)/\\\1/g')/$(echo $newline | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g; s/\([[&()/\]]\)/\\\1/g')/g"
```

will do what you want.